# Switching slider input colors without flickering

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am trying to make a shiny app switches colors of a slider input under certain conditions along with an update. The example below demonstrates an imperfect version of what I am trying to do. It simply has a slider input, and two buttons. The two buttons use `updateSliderInput` function to change some properties of the slider, then I use `shinyjs` to add a class to the slider that causes it's color to change.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    includeCSS('www/style.css'),
    useShinyjs(),
    sliderInput("slider",
                "A slider",
                min = 1,
                max = 50,
                value = 30),
    actionButton('type1','type 1'),
    actionButton('type2','type 2')

))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

    observeEvent(input$type1,{
        updateSliderInput(session,
                          inputId = 'slider',
                          min = 0,
                          value = 10,
                          max = 20)
        delay(3,{
            removeClass(selector = '.js-irs-0', class = 'type2')
            addClass(selector = '.js-irs-0', class = 'type1')
        })
    })

    observeEvent(input$type2,{
        updateSliderInput(session,
                          inputId = 'slider',
                          min = 0,
                          value = 20,
                          max = 40)
        delay(3,{
            removeClass(selector = '.js-irs-0', class = 'type1')
            addClass(selector = '.js-irs-0', class = 'type2')
        })
    })

})
```

(www/css file is at the end of the question as it's contents are less relevant)

In a fast system, the results look fine as there is little delay between the execution of the lines. However, if I switch to a slower machine, you can see the slider flickering back to its original blue, when switching between the colors provided by `type1` and `type2`. This happens because `updateSliderInput` removes any classes manually added to the slider when applying its own updates. I am looking for a way to prevent this from happening. I suspect it can be done using `session$sendCustomMessage` or `session$sendInputMessage` but I haven't been successful so far.

Notes: The `delay` function was necessary because without it, the `updateSliderInput` overrode the changes performed by `addClass`. `removeClass` isn't strictly necessary as `updateSliderInput` already removes manually added classes but I kept the line since the fix will possibly involve preventing `updateSliderInput` from doing that.

As promised:

**www/style.css**

```
.type1 .irs-bar {
border-top-color: #8B1A1A;
border-bottom-color: #8B1A1A;
}

.type1 .irs-bar-edge {
border-color: #8B1A1A;
}

.type1 .irs-single, .type1 .irs-bar-edge, .type1 .irs-bar {
background: #8B1A1A;
}

.type2 .irs-bar {
border-top-color: #6959CD;
border-bottom-color: #6959CD;
}

.type2 .irs-bar-edge {
border-color: #6959CD;
}

.type2 .irs-single, .type2 .irs-bar-edge, .type2 .irs-bar {
background: #6959CD;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the javsacript code in shiny for updating a slider input (the `input_binding_slider.js` file), shiny calls the slider's own library's API function to do the update. I just tried running this update line myself in the javascript console, and it indeed clears any custom classes (I suspect it's not literally clearing the class, but rather it's probably just rebuilding the HTML and doesn't care about trying to retain any random unexpected classes that were added).

I don't have a beautiful perfect solution for you, but there are a few alternative options you may or may not like:

Solution 1: add the class to a parent div of the input, and slightly change your CSS selector accordingly (my recommended solution)

Solution 2: instead of an updateSliderInput, use uiOutput+renderUI, and in the renderUI you can generate a slider input that already has the given class when it gets built (using `htmltools::tagAppendAttributes()`) (more work but can work)

Solution 3: use your own javascript to do the update and add the class immediately (not recommended)

Note: I wasn't able to replicate the flickering issue so I haven't actually checked that the specific problem is solved, but I suspect it could help.

Note 2: I think `delay(0, ...)` would do, I don't think you need to put a positive number there

Comment: Switching to this as the answer as solution 1 allows use within modules unlike my post below

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with adding classes and trying to prevent `updateSliderInput` from overwriting them, one can switch the default color of the slider at will so no flickering will happen as demonstrated in the code below.

Note that this approach still has its problems. For instance if you are writing a module that relies on this, I do not know of an easy way to detect what is the id for your own slider so you can correctly edit the default coloration.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    includeCSS('www/type1.css'), # your initial look
    htmlOutput('defaultSlider'), # update to change colors
    sliderInput("slider",
                "A slider",
                min = 1,
                max = 50,
                value = 30),
    actionButton('type1','type 1'),
    actionButton('type2','type 2')

))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {


    observeEvent(input$type1,{
        updateSliderInput(session,
                          inputId = 'slider',
                          min = 0,
                          value = 10,
                          max = 20)

        output$defaultSlider = renderUI({
            includeCSS('www/type1.css')
        })
    })

    observeEvent(input$type2,{
        updateSliderInput(session,
                          inputId = 'slider',
                          min = 0,
                          value = 20,
                          max = 40)

        output$defaultSlider = renderUI({
            includeCSS('www/type2.css')
        })
    })
})
```

www/type1.css

```
.js-irs-0 .irs-bar {
    border-top-color: #8B1A1A;
        border-bottom-color: #8B1A1A;
}

.js-irs-0 .irs-bar-edge {
    border-color: #8B1A1A;
}

.js-irs-0 .irs-single, .js-irs-0 .irs-bar-edge, .js-irs-0 .irs-bar {
    background: #8B1A1A;
}
```

www/type2.css

```
.js-irs-0 .irs-bar {
    border-top-color: #6959CD;
        border-bottom-color: #6959CD;
}

.js-irs-0 .irs-bar-edge {
    border-color: #6959CD;
}

.js-irs-0 .irs-single, .js-irs-0 .irs-bar-edge, .js-irs-0 .irs-bar {
    background: #6959CD;
}
```